# AngularJS - Integers returned as null in nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm having a problem with pulling integer values from nested JSON in AngularJS. Strings from the same layer and all data from parent layers are pulling in fine, however numbers are being treated as 'null'. Everything else appears to be working correctly.

E.g. - 'thumbnail', a string, is pulling in fine, whereas thumbnail-height, an integer value on the same layer of JSON, is apparently null.

A stripped down version of my code is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P%7BhilLynx/gabdjacz) with examples of the data I'm trying to pull out, and I've pasted it in below.

In a nutshell, I'm wondering why **{{ card.acf.thumbnail_image.sizes.thumbnail-height }}** is returning 'null'.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions as to why this isn't working!

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ ]);

app.controller('CardController', function($scope,$http) {
    var data = 
[
   {
      "ID":5303,
      "acf":{
         "thumbnail_image":{
            "width":2286,
            "sizes":{
               "thumbnail":"thumbnail1.png",
               "thumbnail-height":91
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "ID":5290,
      "acf":{
         "thumbnail_image":{
            "width":1369,
            "sizes":{
               "thumbnail":"thumbnail2.png",
               "thumbnail-height":80
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
    $scope.dataList = data;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="CardController as tc">

        <ul>http://jsfiddle.net/axrys5cr/1/#fork
            <li ng-repeat="card in dataList">
                <h1>{{card.ID}}</h1>
            <p>card.acf: {{ card.acf }}</p>

            <hr>
            <p>card.acf.thumbnail_image.width: {{ card.acf.thumbnail_image.width }}</p>
            <hr>
                <p><b>card.acf.thumbnail_image.sizes.thumbnail-height:</b> {{ card.acf.thumbnail_image.sizes.thumbnail-height }}</p>
                <p><b>card.acf.thumbnail_image.sizes.thumbnail:</b> {{ card.acf.thumbnail_image.sizes.thumbnail }}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{ card.acf.thumbnail_image.sizes.thumbnail-height }}`

should be

`{{ card.acf.thumbnail_image.sizes['thumbnail-height']}}` because `thumbnail-height` key contains a invalid char `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Keys cannot contain a hyphen `-` when using [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation). So when you bind to:

```
{{ card.acf.thumbnail_image.sizes.thumbnail-height }}
```

What you're actually saying is : `card.acf.thumbnail_image.sizes.thumbnail` *minus* `height`.

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) instead:

```
{{ card.acf.thumbnail_image.sizes["thumbnail-height"] }}
```